# div scrollable with fixed div

Tags: html, css, scrollable

I am trying to figure out how to make a basic page setup based on the old index set up with a fixed header/navbar div of let's say 200px height. A second div below with the page content should be scrollable and fit the remaining vertical space inside the browser window. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds like you simply are looking for `position: fixed`. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your CSS Part, this will make the div unscrollable!
`overflow: auto;` makes the Div scrollable again

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/v596fvbu/

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the navbar fixed and let the body scroll underneath it:

```
.navbar {
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

http://codepen.io/helb/pen/EWjPqJ

or limit the page height to browser window size and make the second div scrollable:

```
.page {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 3em); /* browser viewport height minus the navbar height */
}
```

http://codepen.io/helb/pen/NpqNxy

Note the difference in scrollbar placement:

[image: scrollbars]